# Show a snackbar from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android

so I am looking to make a tasker plugin that shows a snackbar with user entered text. The problem I am having is that I have to show the snackbar from a broadcast receiver. I thought I found a way by passing the activity context from an activity class, but the app just crashes. All help is much appreciated.

Here is the receiver class:

```
public final class FireReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Maker maker;

    /**
     * @param context {@inheritDoc}.
     * @param intent  the incoming {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#ACTION_FIRE_SETTING} Intent. This
     *                should contain the {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE} that was saved by
     *                {@link SnackbarActivity} and later broadcast by Locale.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        /*
         * Always be strict on input parameters! A malicious third-party app could send a malformed Intent.
         */
        if (!com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.ACTION_FIRE_SETTING.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (Constants.IS_LOGGABLE)
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "Received unexpected Intent action %s", intent.getAction())); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return;
        }

        BundleScrubber.scrub(intent);

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE);
        BundleScrubber.scrub(bundle);

        if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(bundle)) {
            final String message = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
            final String button = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_BUTTON);
            final String mode = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MODE);
            if (maker == null) {
                maker = new Maker();
            }
            //maker.createSnackbar(message, button, mode);
            Snackbar.make(maker.getView(), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction(button, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Maker class:

```
public class Maker extends Activity {

    public void createSnackbar(String Main, String Button, String Mode) {
        if (Mode.equals("Short")) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Main, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction(Button, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }).show();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Main, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(Button, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }).show();
        }
    }

    public View getView() {
        View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought I found a way by passing the activity context from an activity class, but the app just crashes

You cannot create a working instance of an activity yourself via a constructor.

> The problem I am having is that I have to show the snackbar from a broadcast receiver.

That's not really possible. You are welcome to start an activity, (perhaps using a dialog theme, that does not take up the whole screen). Or, you can show a `Toast`. Or, you can raise a `Notification`. Those are your primary UI options from a `BroadcastReceiver`. A `Snackbar` is designed for use from an activity, not from a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: ok, dang. Was really hoping this was possible. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JoeSmith I will have to respectfully disagree with @CommonsWare. This is possible if the context is an instance of an `Activity` - we could make use of `android.R.id.content` to retrieve the root view of the activity and pass it to the `SnackBar`

Comment: @Abhijit: The question is about creating a Tasker plugin. `FireReceiver` is going to have to be registered in the manifest. When `FireReceiver` is called with `onReceive()`, there may not be an activity anywhere in the app's process, as that process might have been created a few milliseconds ago. Even if there *is* an activity, it's probably not in the foreground, and so having that activity show a `Snackbar` will not be visible to the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the clarification. I stand corrected

Comment: Hey guys, I ended up making this by just showing an invisible activity and showing the snackbar like that. The only problem I am having now is allowing the user to tap the screen below as well as the snackbar.